# how to know which module a frontname belongs to just looking at the url in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento

For example: 
The url is

```
index.php/catalogsearch/advanced/
```

how to find out which module it belongs to ? In this case I know that the frontname is "catalogsearch", the controller is "advanced" and the method is "indexAction" ? But to what module does it belong?

In this case it is easy because the name of the frontname and the name of the module match but if they were different? how can we find the module of the frontname ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is here, in the config.xml file of the module Mage_CatalogSearch :

```
<routers>
        <catalogsearch>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_CatalogSearch</module>
                <frontName>catalogsearch</frontName>
            </args>
        </catalogsearch>
 </routers>
```

So I hope you have a good IDE which allows you to perform searches on all files. If you're unable to perform a search, you could edit a template used in the page of the URL you're after, and dump this in a log file :

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerModule();
```

This will give you `"Mage_CatalogSearch"`. Additionnally, you might want to use these methods too :

```
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName();
Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName();
```

Comment: Thanks. I use phpstorm ide. I can use "find in path" to search frontname.

Comment: @ChenHanhan easy then. Don't forget to mark this as the accepted answer if it suits your needs !

Comment: @ChenHanhan it's not a vote, it's the "check" symbol under the answer's score

Comment: OK。This question is checked

Answer (score 0):

//Write below code in index.php file or any phtml files.

```
/**
 * get module name
 */
$this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
```

[More details got through the this link.](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-get-controller-action-and-module-name-in-template-file/)